# Understanding Markov Chains

Tags: probability, statistics, summation, markov-chains

Recently, in my computer science class, we implemented a Markov Chain in Python to generate the probability of a certain word appearing after another. Syntactically, it's easy enough to understand. However, my issues arise when trying to understand it in mathematical notation.

I have constructed a Markov Chain where $$p_{1,1}=\frac13$$ $$p_{1,2}=\frac23$$ $$p_{2,1}=1$$$$p_{2,2}=0$$

I also have that $v_0=(1,0)$. From this, *I'm trying to calculate the probability of being in state 1 after exactly 2 steps*. My first attempt was to look at the *Law Of Probability* for Markov Chains, but I'm not quite aware of the explicit arguments I would input for this. Drawing out the Markov Chain is no issue; it's merely a matter of figuring out probabilities.

First, **I tried to calculate the probability of being in state 1**; that is,

$$P(X_t=1) \sum_{i}^{} P(X_t = 1\mid X_{t-1}=i)P(X_{t-1}=i)$$

However, I am unsure of the explicit arguments I would pass in.

Comment: In this specific example, you might be better off with a picture.  Note that to be in state 1 after exactly two steps having started in state one, you will either remain motionless twice in a row (*with probability $\frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{3}$*) or you will leave state 1 to 2 and then return back (*with probability $\frac{2}{3}\cdot 1$*).  Note further the relationship between the stochastic matrix formed with these values and the powers of that matrix.

Comment: Thanks @JMoravitz I realize now that there is no way to return back to state 2; thus, it makes it easier since this ensures starting at state 1 makes us return to state 1. Would this also mean the probability of being at state one is simply 1/3 since you will always go back to 1 from state 2 and ($\frac13 \cdot 1 = \frac13$)

Comment: Perhaps your notation is following a different pattern than what I am used to causing some confusion with my earlier comment.  My interpretation was that $p_{i,j}$ is the probability of moving to state $j$ given that you began in state $i$.  Here, we have four possible paths that we could follow given that we begin in state 1:  (From 1 to 1 to 1), (From 1 to 1 to 2), (From 1 to 2 to 1), (From 1 to 2 to 2).  Each of these are mutually exclusive outcomes.  It is possible then that having started at state 1 that we end in state 2 after two steps (following 1>1>2) despite (1>2>2) having prob 0.

Comment: @JMoravitz I completely understand that - you were very clear and informative on your previous comment. Sorry for the confusion; in my question, I attempted to solve the *probability of being at state one.* Although it is not necessary to understand your answer, it is still something I'd like to understand so I more clearly understand how to go about using Markov Chains.

Comment: I am confused then why you thought to multiply $\frac{1}{3}$ and $1$ together.  Following my earlier comments a bit more closely, we add the probabilities of following the path (1>1>1) and (1>2>1) together, this being $\frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{3}+\frac{2}{3}\cdot 1$  (i.e. $p_{1,1}p_{1,1}+p_{1,2}p_{2,1}$).  For larger number of steps away, this becomes tedious to do by hand, and so using matrices and raising our matrix to the appropriate power is much more convenient.

Comment: @JMoravitz My apologizes for being incredibly vague here. There were two probabilities I was trying to solve. The first was the *probability of being in state 1 after two steps* which you very cleanly helped me understand was just $\frac13 \cdot \frac13 + \frac23 \cdot 1$. The other probability I was trying to understand was just simply *the probability of being at state one* by itself. I was trying to use your intuition for the first probability to go about the second one. Again, my apologizes for the inconsistencies.

Comment: "*the probability of being at state one*" is too vague... are you talking about after a specific amount of time?  After an indefinite large amount of time?  Are you talking about being at state one at least once over the course of a window of time?  Each of these are different questions.  The most commonly asked one is "after an indefinite large amount of time" which is asking essentially for the stablestate distribution.  In essence you need to find the eigenvector for the eigenvalue of $1$ for your stochastic matrix, i.e. solving $(A-I)x=0$, i.e. finding kernel of $(A-I)$

Comment: @JMoravitz I'm assuming a steady-state distribution. Thus, I believe time or steps is irrelevant since the probability of being in State One will be the same now and in the future at any time. At least that's what I believe that means.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56136/discussion-between-jmoravitz-and-digital-veer).

Comment: Was the probability of being INITIALLY in state $1$ given? $\qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you wrote $v_0=(1,0)$, I'm guessing you meant the probabilities of being initially in states $1$ and $2$ are respectively $1$ and $0$, i.e. you know you're initially in state $1$.

To be in state $1$ after two steps means either you stayed in state $1$ throughout the process or you went to state $2$ at the first step and returned to state $1$ at the second step.
$$
\Pr( 1 \mapsto 1 \mapsto 1) + \Pr(1\mapsto 2\mapsto 1) = \left(\frac 1 3\cdot\frac 1 3\right) + \left(\frac 2 3 \cdot 1\right) = \frac 1 9 + \frac 2 3 = \frac 7 9.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Make a matrix $\mathbf P$ using the four $p_{ij}$'s you have.
Then square the matrix (using the rules of matrix multiplication).
Then element $(1,1)$ of $\mathbf P^2,$ often written as $p_{11}^{(2)},$
is the probability you seek.

This answer should match the the
one provided in the 2nd Comment of @JMoravitz. The only advantage of
my method is that $\mathbf P^n$ would give you the answer $p_{11}^{(n)}$ to questions
such as, "Starting in state $1$, what is the probability I'll be back in state $1$ at step $n$?"

The Chapman-Kolmogorov equations can be used to show that
the $n$th power of the transition matrix has the property I'm claiming.

**Addendum. Long-run probability of being in state 1.**

*Intuitive:* Imagine a round trip from state $1$ to state $2$ and then back
to state $1.$ How long does an average trip take? You leave state $1$
with probability $2/3,$ so the geometric average waiting time to leave
is $3/2 = 1.5$ steps. Then you spend exactly one step in state $2.$
So the average round trip takes $2.5$ steps, of which $1.5$ is spent in
state $1.$ In the long run you spend $\frac{1.5}{2.5} = 3/5$ of time in
state $1.$ [This method always works when there is only one possible path for a
round trip, as in a 2-state Markov chain, or a sufficiently simple
chain with more than two states.]

*Algebraic:* For this simple chain, the long-run probabilties are also
the steady state probabilities. The vector $\mathbf\sigma = (\sigma_1, \sigma_2)$
is a steady state distribution if $\mathbf\sigma \mathbf P = \mathbf\sigma.$ It is easy algebra
to solve the resulting equation $\frac{2}{3}\sigma_1 + \sigma_2 = \sigma_1$ along
with the obvious $\sigma_1 + \sigma_2 = 1$ to get $\sigma_1 = 3/5$ and
$\sigma_2 = 2/5.$ [The second equation from $\mathbf\sigma \mathbf P = \mathbf\sigma$ is 
$\frac{2}{3}\sigma_1 = \sigma_2,$ which is redundant. When there are two
states and $\mathbf P$ is a $2 \times 2$ matrix, one of the two equations from 
$\mathbf\sigma \mathbf P = \mathbf\sigma$ will *always* be redundant.] As @JMoravitz also Commented, for chains with more
states, you can use find the eigen vectors of $\mathbf P$ (with a computer if
convenient), but no
need for that here.